# How to insert NULL value in SQL nvarchar column using python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am trying to insert None from python in SQL table, but it is inserting as string 'null'

I am using below set of code.

```
query_update = f'''update table set Name = '{name}',Key = '{Key}' where Id = {id} '''
            stmt.execute(query_update)
            conn.commit()
```

I am getting values in python for variable 'Key' these values I am trying to update in column "Key". These two columns are nvarchar columns.

Now sometime we get None values Null in variable 'Key' as below

Key = 'Null'

So when I insert above value in SQL it is getting updated as string instead of NULL, as I had to put quote in script while updating from Python.

Can anyone help me here, How can I avoid inserting string while inserting Null in SQL from Python

Comment: Don't use `f`-strings (or any other string formatting) to paramerize SQL queries. It's not safe. Do it as shown in [the docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters). And it will also fix your problem when using `None`.

Comment: yes agree, your problem is the quotes and how you are generating that string

Answer (score 0):

The problem that your `Null` values are actually a string and not "real" Null.
If you want to insert Null, your key should be equal to `None`.

You can can convert it as follows:
`Key = Key if Key != 'Null' else None`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is that you are placing quotes around the placeholders. Have a look how I think the same can be done.

```
query_update = 'update table set Name = {name}, Key = {Key} where Id = {id}'
query_update.format(name='myname', Key = 'mykey', Id = 123)
stmt.execute(query_update)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use dynamic SQL. Use a proper *parameterized query*:

```python
# test data
name = "Gord"
key = None  # not a string
id = 1

query_update = "update table_name set Name = ?, Key = ? where Id = ?"
stmt.execute(query_update, name, key, id)
conn.commit()
```